# Cascading Select in Javascript and Telerik RadFormDecorator

Tags: telerik, telerik-radformdecorator

I am trying very hard to make my cascading select decorate using telerik form decorator. Here is my js,

```
var attributes = s.attributes;
        for (var i = 0, iLen = attributes.length; i < iLen ; i++) {
            $elem.append('<option ' + (selectedValue === attributes[i].id ? 'selected ' : '') + 'value="' + attributes[i].id + '">' + attributes[i].name + '</option>');
        }
```

after this I am calling,

```
formDecorator.decorate($elem[0], false);
```

It only works first time when the parent select changed(in a cascading select). But after this nothing works. I have tried,

```
formDecorator.decorate();
```

and

```
formDecorator.updateSelect($elem[0]);
```

Is there is any way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

A quick search in Telerik's forums gave me this thread that seems to have a useful response: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/form-decorator/cascading-select-in-javascrip-and-telerik-radformdecorator.aspx. I would give it a try and post there for more people to see. I hope it helps you.